# Implementing a struct (C-Code) in RISC-V Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, riscv

I'm wondering how to convert a simple struct like this into RISC-V:
`static struct {int x, y}`
Can someone help me with this? Thanks!
update:
This is the full C-Code:

```
static struct { int x, y } v = { 7, 3 };
int d2 = v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y;
```

And this are my thoughts on it:

```
    v:
    .word 7
    .word 3
    x:
    .int 0
    y:
    .int 1
```

But i don't really know how to continue.

Comment: Which part do you need help with? To allocate you can just do `x: .int 0; y: .int 0` or whatever directive your assembler that you did not specify uses.

Comment: I updated my question. Now you see what i want to implement

Comment: Well, for that you only need 2 fields, not 4. You can do: `v.x: .word 7; v.y: .word 3`.

Comment: but the declaration of v is given to me. I can't change that

Comment: Then you don't need anything else. You can address `v` and `v+4`. Alternatively, using whatever syntax your assembler supports, you can declare aliases e.g. `.equ v.x, v` and `.equ v.y, v+4` if that works.

Comment: v includes 7 and there. How can i access des two values?

Comment: You've got some data, so the next step is to write some code, maybe try `la` and `lw`.

Comment: Also, have a look at what a compiler generates for some C code, e.g. godbolt.org.

Comment: Do you care about your asm source actually using names like `x`, instead of `v` and `v+4`?  If so, then read the manual for your assembler to see if it says anything about struct syntax.  If not, then just do what compilers do, like Erik suggested on https://godbolt.org/